# Which achievements are disabled when changing difficulties mid-game?

Tags: achievements, deus-ex-human-revolution

When trying to change the difficulty during a game a warning is shown that "some achievements will not be unlocked". Which achievements are affected by a difficulty change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only affected achievement is Legend, which requires beating the game on Give Me Deus Ex difficulty (hardest). If you want to get that achievement, you must start a game on Give Me Deus Ex difficulty and never change it.

PS: I encourage playing on Give me Deus Ex difficulty. That is the way the game was meant to be played.

Comment: Ok, so the warning is rather stupid when switching from easy to normal.

Comment: They probably hadn't decided whether to put an achievement limited to normal+ until late in the process.